# Mis-aligned images on fluid/percentage based layout

Tags: css, image, image-scaling, fluid-layout, liquid-layout

I have this code: http://jsfiddle.net/VV9qJ/ but for some reason I cannot seem to fix the little pixel errors caused by the images. Basically you'll notice that some of the images have a pixel or two white gap around some of them whilst some do not, especially when you resize the browser window. Each browser renders the white gaps slightly differently as well.

My layout must not have any gaps and all content must be tight up against each other, including the browser window.

Is there a fool-proof method of ensuring the images remain tight up against one another at all times across different browsers? jQuery perhaps? I've done loads of Googling but found nothing on this.

Still haven't found a fix for this. I find it hard to believe that a solution isn't out there, can anyone help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm not understanding what's wrong, I can't seem to reproduce the problem with the white gaps, but it sounds like it could be a margin or padding problem.

```
div.smallLink {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
```

You might also have to set margin and padding on img tags within .smallLink to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code under your groupoflink div

letter-spacing: -4px;

http://jsfiddle.net/VV9qJ/11/

Comment: I agree with @VivekChandra that doesn't solve my problem unfortunately

Comment: It removed 4px space (whitespace) between two adjacent inline-blocks.

Comment: Yes but the pixel gaps are random depending on both the browser your using and the size the window is. For example I see vertical gaps as well as horizontal ones but not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the `width:100%` on the div with the class `content` ..

while the div bearing the class `banner` is also set to `100%` width occupies the complete `100%` of the space,but when your subdividing the 100% into `50% + 50%` what's happening is that its dividing the 100% width say - 500 into 250 + 250 for you sub divisions.But the division happens properly only when the width taken by its parent( since its dynamic) is an `EVEN NUMBER`.. i.e, 2(n) ..

else,the 50% division doesnt happen properly,say 501 was the space available which means the div's with 100% width will take up the complete space which is 501 -- but the child div's with 50% width will get `250px` and `250px` leaving behind that `1px gap that your noticing!!..

To remove the white space give a `background-color` so that you can overlook the `1px` white space that creeps up!!

This isnt the best method to overcome this -- there should be a css way which i'm unable to think of right now.. so,here's a JS solution..

```
function load(){
var largelink = document.getElementById("largelink");
largelink.nextSibling.style.width = largelink.parentNode.offsetWidth-largelink.offsetWidth + "px";
}
window.onload = load;
window.resize = load;​
```

i.e,Parent -- if 501 and the 1st child with 50% will be 250 hence the second child will be 501-250 + "px"

Edited only 1 set of your HTML ( you should do the same for the rest ) -- changed to get the id of the parent( 15 its 501 ) and the largelin ( if its 501 - this would be 250 )

```
<div id="largeLink" class="largeLink">
```

Havnt tested it.. hope it works..

Comment: Ok thanks for your explanation, that makes sense. Do you know of a jQuery method that could fix it rather than just using a background color? Images are likely to change and will range in colour so a line will be noticeable at some point.

Comment: Thanks for this @VivekChandra but unfortunately this didn't work. White gaps still appear. Plus ID's can only be used once on a page. I thought there would be a pure CSS way to fix this also but no luck so far.